# Create Android Emulator Hardware Profile without hardware feature android.hardware.touchscreen

Tags: android, xml, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to emulate a feature phone such as the Sonim XP3, which does not have a touch screen.  I do not see an option for this in the AVD wizard for creating a hardware profile.  I do see that I can import a hardware profile and that the xml of an exported hardware profile looks like this

```
<d:devices xmlns:d="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/devices/5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <d:device>
    <d:name>Pixel XL</d:name>
    <d:id>pixel_xl</d:id>
    <d:manufacturer>Google</d:manufacturer>
    <d:meta/>
    <d:hardware>
      <d:screen>
        <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
        <d:diagonal-length>5.50</d:diagonal-length>
        <d:pixel-density>560dpi</d:pixel-density>
        <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
        <d:dimensions>
          <d:x-dimension>1440</d:x-dimension>
          <d:y-dimension>2560</d:y-dimension>
        </d:dimensions>
        <d:xdpi>534.04</d:xdpi>
        <d:ydpi>534.04</d:ydpi>
        <d:touch>
          <d:multitouch>jazz-hands</d:multitouch>
          <d:mechanism>finger</d:mechanism>
          <d:screen-type>capacitive</d:screen-type>
        </d:touch>
      </d:screen>
      <d:networking>
Bluetooth
Wifi
NFC</d:networking>
      <d:sensors>
Accelerometer
Barometer
Compass
GPS
Gyroscope
LightSensor
ProximitySensor</d:sensors>
      <d:mic>true</d:mic>
      <d:camera>
        <d:location>back</d:location>
        <d:autofocus>true</d:autofocus>
        <d:flash>true</d:flash>
      </d:camera>
      <d:camera>
        <d:location>front</d:location>
        <d:autofocus>true</d:autofocus>
        <d:flash>false</d:flash>
      </d:camera>
      <d:keyboard>nokeys</d:keyboard>
      <d:nav>nonav</d:nav>
      <d:ram unit="GiB">4</d:ram>
      <d:buttons>soft</d:buttons>
      <d:internal-storage unit="GiB">
32</d:internal-storage>
      <d:removable-storage unit="TiB">
0</d:removable-storage>
      <d:cpu>Quad Core 2x 2.15GHz / 2x 1.6GHz (Qualcomm Snapdragon 821)</d:cpu>
      <d:gpu>Adreno 530</d:gpu>
      <d:abi>
armeabi
armeabi-v7a
arm64-v8a</d:abi>
      <d:dock/>
      <d:power-type>battery</d:power-type>
      <d:skin>pixel_xl_silver</d:skin>
    </d:hardware>
    <d:software>
      <d:api-level>25-25</d:api-level>
      <d:live-wallpaper-support>true</d:live-wallpaper-support>
      <d:bluetooth-profiles/>
      <d:gl-version>3.2</d:gl-version>
      <d:gl-extensions>
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_EGL_image_external
GL_OES_EGL_sync
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_framebuffer_object
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr
GL_OES_texture_compression_astc
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float
GL_QCOM_alpha_test
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map
GL_EXT_sRGB
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_EXT_copy_image
GL_EXT_geometry_shader
GL_EXT_tessellation_shader
GL_OES_texture_stencil8
GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks
GL_OES_shader_image_atomic
GL_OES_sample_variables
GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp
GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture
GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation
GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array
GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed
GL_EXT_gpu_shader5
GL_EXT_robustness
GL_EXT_texture_buffer
GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch
GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil
GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array
GL_OES_sample_shading
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_EXT_debug_label
GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a
GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_vertex_array_object
GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
GL_KHR_debug
GL_EXT_YUV_target
GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control
GL_EXT_texture_norm16
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
GL_OES_surfaceless_context
GL_OVR_multiview
GL_OVR_multiview2
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8
GL_KHR_no_error
GL_EXT_debug_marker
GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3
GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture
GL_EXT_buffer_storage
GL_EXT_blit_framebuffer_params
GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance
GL_EXT_protected_textures</d:gl-extensions>
      <d:status-bar>true</d:status-bar>
    </d:software>
    <d:state default="true" name="Portrait">
      <d:description>The phone in portrait view</d:description>
      <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
      <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
      <d:nav-state>navhidden</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
    <d:state name="Landscape">
      <d:description>The phone in landscape view</d:description>
      <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
      <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
      <d:nav-state>navhidden</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
  </d:device>
</d:devices>
```

I see that there is a `<d:screen-type>capactive</d:screen-type>`
Is there someway to modify this file to have a screen that is not a touch screen?  Is there a way to browse the schema http://schemas.android.com/sdk/devices/5 ?
Putting this url in my browser gives me an error.